# VS Code - 'mcs' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: visual-studio-code, mono

When i tried to run the program for the first time, it crashes and this is what i got. im sure that i've installed mono sdk

```
PS D:\Microsoft VS Code\Projects\New Projects> cd "d:\Microsoft VS Code\Projects\New Projects\" ; if ($?) { mcs Program.cs -out:Program } ; if ($?) { mono Program }

mcs : The term 'mcs' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:62
+ ... "d:\Microsoft VS Code\Projects\New Projects\" ; if ($?) { mcs Program ...        
+                                                               ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mcs:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**strong text**
```

Comment: but is the bin directory of mono on your path?

Comment: Mono SDK on Windows does not install anything to Windows PATH, so you cannot expect commands like `mcs` to work immediately. In general, why do you choose to use Mono instead of .NET Core when the latter is replacing the former?

Comment: what should i do to fix this? i think i need to learn it more :3